# Jquery addclass after scrolling 500px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass, scrolltop

I want to add a class to a div after scrolling 500px down the page using jquery. I found a way of doing it but it's an immediate transition, I want to be able to controll how long it takes to add the class like with the normal Jquery addclass.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $(".nav").addClass("navnewclass");
    }
});
```

I tried doing this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $(".nav").addClass("navnewclass", 2000);
    }
});
```

but it was the same.

Comment: I believe he's talking about the transitioning between two classes when using `.toggleClass` with jQueryUI. **EDIT** Oh, you already answered. Duh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to controll how long it takes to add the class like with the normal Jquery addclass.

`addClass` is *always* instantaneous, it's not part of the animation suite.

There are plug-ins that will do class-based animations for you (most notably [jQuery UI's `addClass` override](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/)), but jQuery itself does not. Simply adding jQuery UI to your page will make your second example work. But there are other options as well.

Your options are to use one of those plug-ins, or animate the properties directly (using [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate)) rather than using a class. Note that jQuery only animates certain kinds of properties (not, notably, colors — jQuery UI adds support for animating colors as well).

Here's an example animating a class (with colors) using jQuery UI: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/umONejI/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/umONejI/1/edit)

```
<style>
.testing {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>

<!-- ...and later in the body... -->

<p>After half a second, the div below will spend two seconds animating the addition of a class.</p>
<div class="nav">This is a test .nav element</div>
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".nav").addClass("testing", 2000);
}, 500);
</script>
```

Comment: Another question, it animates when I scroll down but is there a way of animating it back when you scroll back to the top?

Answer (score 0):

IT WILL WORK FINE FOR ME.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
if (scroll >= 500) {
setTimeout('$(".nav").addClass("navnewclass")',1000);
}
});
```

instead of 1000 U can just set your time.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using jQuery or $ sign

example:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 100) {
        $("#logo-not-scroll").addClass("blue1");
    }
    else{
        $("#logo-not-scroll").removeClass("blue1");
    }
});
```

or

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 100) {
            jQuery("#logo-not-scroll").addClass("blue1");
        }
        else{
            jQuery("#logo-not-scroll").removeClass("blue1");
        }
});
```